# (Dis)Advantages of correlation vs. $R^2$ vs. p-value of linear regression for two variables?

Tags: correlation, p-value

I would like to know what are advantages and disadvantages of $R^2$ vs. correlation (e.g. `cor()` in R) vs. p-value of linear regression for two variables/features? What other ways exist to measure whether two variables/features correlate?

Comment: What do you mean by "$R^2$ vs correlation"? Those two measures are used for *different* purposes. Also for assessing correlation you use correlation... What do you want to measure? Could you be more precise in your question as now it is not really clear what you are asking.

Answer (score -1):

1) Note: R-squared is simply the square of Pearson's correlation coefficient

Disadvantages:

1) R^2 and r are only appropriate for linear relationships, so if there is a nonlinear relationship then, generally speaking although not always, r will fail to detect the relationship (you can test this by generating fake data for two variables and calculating the correlation)

2) The use of r also assumes that there is a bivariate normal distribution between the two variables (this is condition is often violated)

P-values vs. R^2:

--> there is a distinction between whether a variable(s) is important versus whether it is statistically significant

An "important" variable means that a variable explains a (relatively large) proportion of the variance in Y, and you can measure importance by looking at the change in the R^2 value for each variable that you add to the model

A statistically significant variable is a variable that has a p-value that is below a certain threshold (commonly this threshold is .05).

The problem with p-values are that they are sensitive to the sample size (please review the concept of "power"). Generally speaking, as the sample size increases, the p-value will decrease (in order to see this, please review the formula for the t-test statistic that is used in order to generate the p-value)

Alternatives:

Spearman's Rank Correlation Coefficient (Advantage: non-parametric, less
sensitive to outliers)

Hoeffding's D (Advantage: non-parametric, can detect some nonlinear relationships)

Kendall's Tau (Advantage: its distribution will converge to a normal distribution faster than other correlation metrics, so this is useful when the sample size is small)